# SwiftUI: How to recreate toolbar style?

Tags: macos, swiftui, appkit

I am trying to recreate the native toolbar style for my custom bottom bar. I applied an NSVisualEffectView, but it looks different. The toolbar is white with blur effect, while my custom bottom bar is gray. Additionally, I don't understand how to recreate a drop shadow because SwiftUI's drop shadow also looks different.

```swift
List {
  Rectangle().fill(.clear).frame(height: 1000)
}
.overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
  VStack {
    TextField("Enter a message...", text: $content)
  }
  .ignoresSafeArea()
  .background(VisualEffectView(material: .titlebar, blendingMode: .withinWindow))
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the `headerView` material and added [`NSShadow`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsshadow) to the [`NSVisualEffectView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsvisualeffectview/). Now it looks like a toolbar.

[image]